# Message: Trying to get property of non-object using CodeIgniter Framework

Tags: php, codeigniter, debugging, frameworks

```
 case "up":
    $current_row = $this -> crud_model -> get('client_list', array('id_client_list' => $entry_id), 'id_client_list', 'asc', '1');
    $affected_row = $this -> crud_model -> get('client_list', array('id_company' => $current_row -> id_company, 'ord' => $current_row -> ord - 1), 'id_client_list', 'asc', '1');
    $this -> crud_model -> save('client_list', array('id_client_list' => $current_row -> id_client_list), array('ord' => $affected_row -> ord));
    $this -> crud_model -> save('client_list', array('id_client_list' => $affected_row -> id_client_list), array('ord' => $current_row -> ord));
```

I get this error:

```
Message: Trying to get property of non-object
```

From what I can tell this is built on top of a framework which makes this harder to understand.

The error is happening on the last two lines. Is this a framework not able to do this or is it a code error?

Comment: Are you sure `$current_row` & `$affected_row` are getting proper values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't returning anything.

```
$current_row = $this->crud_model->get('client_list', array('id_client_list' => $entry_id), 'id_client_list', 'asc', '1')->row();
$affected_row = $this->crud_model->get('client_list', array('id_company' => $current_row->id_company, 'ord' => $current_row->ord - 1), 'id_client_list', 'asc', '1')->row();
$this->crud_model->save('client_list', array('id_client_list' => $current_row->id_client_list), array('ord' => $affected_row->ord));
$this->crud_model->save('client_list', array('id_client_list' => $affected_row->id_client_list), array('ord' => $current_row->ord));
```

Added `->row();` at the end.

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined method stdClass::row() when I try that